# How to manage components values

Tags: cfml

I'm learning Coldfusion components, and I have a component named `Page.cfc`, what is the common practice, if any, to store local values when calling functions? That is, should the function return the value, or is it better to store the values in the object, so to access it later, like:

```cfml
<cfcomponent>
<cffunction name="upcase">
  <cfset this.name = ucase(this.name)>
  <cfreturn>
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="upcase">
  <cfargument name="what">
  <cfreturn ucase(arguments.word)>
</cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

Thanks!

Comment: depends on what your code / object wants to do. you may be best of to start reading some books on object oriented programming deciding when to do what with different variables and variables scopes is the art of programming. There is no answer to your question besides: it depends....

Comment: In general, if the component contains library functions, you return the value. If the component corresponds to an object in your model, a Page, then you might store the value in the component. In the latter case, you might use mixins to load library functions into the object at runtime, so that upcase() reside in a different component, not Page.cfc, and is only loaded there when needed. See a discussion of mixins in OOP for more details.